# applied my model on set 1 shape (23450, 6729) & set 2 -shape (23450, 611). Here, set 2 is smaller than set 1 but why it took 4 times longer than set 1

Tags: machine-learning, time-complexity, decision-tree, gridsearchcv

Below is my code:

this code took 172m to run,

```
         
param_grid = {'max_depth': [3, 5],'n_estimators': [100, 200]}

gbdt = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=42)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(gbdt, param_grid, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc', return_train_score=True)
grid_search.fit(X_train_set_1, y_train)
```

however, when i applied it on second set of data it is still running since 350+ mins.

here, the shape of `X_train_set_1, y_train is: (23450, 6729) (23450,)`

and `param_grid = {'max_depth': [3, 5],'n_estimators': [100, 200]}`

so i've computed The `time complexity of the code as: O(12 x n_samples x max_depth x n_estimators x n_features)`

Since, GridSearchCV will perform an exhaustive search over all possible combinations of the values of max_depth and n_estimators
So
it will first fit the model with max_depth=3 and n_estimators=100,

then with max_depth=3 and n_estimators=200,

then with max_depth=5 and n_estimators=100, and

finally with max_depth=5 and n_estimators=200

but  the number of features is fixed for all the models being trained.

we can simply say the total number of model fits will be 4 x 3 = 12, and

the `time complexity will be O(12 x n_samples x max_depth x n_estimators x n_features)`

since n_samples is the number of samples in the dataset i.e. 23450
and n_features is the total number of features in the dataset i.e. 6729

Thus if i compute it this will be `O(12 x 23450 x max_depth x n_estimators x 6729)`  
The time complexity of the code is `O(12 x 23450 x max_depth x n_estimators x 6729) = O(12 x 23450 x 5 x 200 x 6729) = O(1893540600000)`

is this observation correct,

based on this i want to know if my second set of data has much lesser features in it i.e. second set of data has shape
`X_train_set_2.shape is (23450, 611) , y_train.shape  is (23450,)`

why the second set is taking longer time to run than the first set

i tried as follows: my CPU is an Intel 12th Gen i7-1250U with 10 physical cores, and 12 logical processors.

it should run the code faster on set 2 than set 1

Comment: Can you post the elapsed time for both cases?

Comment: I am trying to apply GBDT on Donors choose dataset,

Comment: I did not include any code to calculate the elapsed time for model training. However, when i stopped everything in my laptop, restarted it fresh and re run my code the model gets trained in 88mins on set 1 and it is running since 100+ mins on set 2 
I also tried running the same code on Google Colab and it took 47 mins on set 1 while i didnt have patience to check it on set 2